# SQLite, CONDITIONAL SUM

Tags: sqlite

```
table_payments

id  id_order   quantity
1.    1.         50
2.    1.         150   
3.    2.         100
4.    2.          20

table_order_details

id.  id_order    total
1.    1.          300
2.    2.          200
```

I need a query to add the payments and subtract the total.

Example:

```
50+150=300-200=100
100+20=200-120=80
```

result of the query: 180

The query adds the payments and subtracts the total and results in the debit.

Thank danny117

```
SELECT
SUM(agenda_detalles.agendadetalle_precio_total) - (

SELECT
SUM(agenda_pagos.agenda_pago_cantidad)
FROM
agenda
JOIN agenda_pagos
ON agenda.agenda_id = agenda_pagos.agenda_id
WHERE agenda_pagado = 1

) AS adeudo
FROM
agenda
JOIN agenda_detalles
ON agenda.agenda_id = agenda_detalles.agendadetalle_agenda_id
WHERE agenda_pagado = 1
```

I solved it in the following way

Comment: select sum(total) -(select sum(quantity) from payments) from orders

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], i.e. a tailored toy database with the sample data. Do so either by using the `.dump? feature or by giving some lines of "create table ...." and "insert ...". Also you should explain more about the logic of what you want to achieve. The "math" lines do not make any sense to me.